# Database schema Desigining

Tags: database, database-design, constraints, schema

Relations:
Student(s_id,name),
Dept(d_id,name),
course(d_id,c_id,name) d_id FK, refrenced from Dept,
Enrolledin(s_id,d_id).

With the given schema, how to form a relation registeredin which should contain information of courses registered by a student but with the constraint that student can only register in the course offered by dept student has been enrolled in.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook/manual with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show what relevant parts you can do & ask 1 specific question re the first place you are stuck.Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. PS See edit help re code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data model uses single technical IDs. Now you are looking for a way to guarantee consistency through your table tree. This is not possible with singe surrogate keys and is indeed the main drawback of this design. Use composite keys instead:

### student (student_no, name)

- Primary key: (student_no)

### department (department_no, name)

- Primary key: (department_no)

### course (department_no, course_no, name)

- Primary key: (department_no, course_no)
- Foreign key: (department_no) references department (department_no)

### enrolled_in (student_no, department_no)

- Primary key: (student_no, department_no)
- Foreign key: (student_no) references student (student_no)
- Foreign key: (department_no) references department (department_no)

### registered_in (student_no, department_no, course_no)

- Primary key: (student_no, department_no, course_no)
- Foreign key: (student_no, department_no) references enrolled_in (student_no, department_no)
- Foreign key: (department_no, course_no) references course (department_no, course_no)

Comment: Hi Thank you very much!

Actually i thought of the same method but then how is it ensured that department_no in [(student_no, department_no) references enrolled_in (student_no, department_no)] is same as department_no in [(department_no, course_no) references course (department_no, course_no)].
confused about this one.

Comment: Hi, I understood thanks a lot! I was trying registered_in (student_no, enrolled_department_no, course_department_no, course_no) hence was confused about how to check equality between them but if we have single department_no referencing from both tables it should be same!
Thank you very much really grateful for your answer